# Are chaotic systems generally non-differentiable w.r.t. initial conditions?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

There is some important background to go over before this question will make any kind of sense, so before calling me out on my poor understanding of dynamical systems, chaos, and differentiabilty, please take the time to read the whole question, and feel free to offer corrections or improvements if you see something that doesn't quite make sense.

Or just skip to the end. I'm not the boss of you.

---

About a week ago, I posed a simple question to myself: what is chaos, and can it be quantified? Specifically, I was curious as to why certain "well-behaved" systems are not generally considered "chaotic" despite considerable variation in the values of there solutions at a sufficient "distance" from the initial condition.

I spent several days reading introductory material, coming up with various definitions, and testing them against well known chaotic-systems. After several attempts at formalizing the notion of "sensitivity to initial conditions", I eventually settled on the following:

> For a system $S$, let $\text{Sol}(S,\mathbf{x}_0)$ be the solution to $S$ with initial condition $\mathbf{x}_0$ (assuming the solution exists and is unique).
>
> A system $T$ is *orderly* iff for a given initial condition $\mathbf{c}$, for real numbers $t,\varepsilon>0$, there exists a real number $\delta>0$ such that for $0<t'<t$, the difference between $\text{Sol}(T,\mathbf{c})(t')$ and $\text{Sol}(T,\mathbf{c}')(t')$ is less than $\varepsilon$ whenever the difference in between $\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{c'}$ is less than $\delta$.
>
> Symbolically, $T$ is orderly iff:
>
> $$\forall \mathbf{c}.\forall t.\forall\varepsilon>0.\exists \delta> 0.\forall\mathbf{c}'.\forall t'<t.\Vert \mathbf{c}'-\mathbf{c}\Vert<\delta\implies\Vert\text{Sol}(T,\mathbf{c}')(t')-\text{Sol}(T,\mathbf{c})(t')\Vert<\varepsilon$$
>
> A system is *chaotic* iff it is not orderly.

While I was not thinking about it at the time (the use of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ was out of habit rather than intent) I realise that this corresponds almost exactly to the statement "$\text{Sol}$ is ($\varepsilon$,$\delta$)-continuous over the set of initial conditions." This motivated me to try and come up with a more analytical definition of "system" - one that would allow concepts like "continuity over the set of initial conditions" to be expressed more precisely:

> A system is a function $S:I\to Y^X$, where $I$ is the space of initial conditions and $Y^X$ is the set of functions from $X\to Y$.
>
> A parametrization of a system $S$ is a set of expressions uniquely satisfied by $S$. For example, $\{f'(x)=f(x),f(0)=c\}$ is a parametrization of the system $S:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^\Bbb{R}; S(c)=\lambda x.ce^x$.

From this point of view, a system $S:I\to Y^X$  is chaotic iff it is not continuous (different definitions of "continous" can be implemented analogously to those used in analysis with minimal effort).

Furthermore, $S$ is chaotic *locally* over $E\subset I$ iff $S$ is not continuous over $E$.

Now, it seems to me that this definition is much narrower than I originally intended. While I have not been able to prove as such (for want of analytical solutions), I have reason to believe that at least one "chaotic system," the Lorenz system, is not chaotic under this definition.

A cursory examination of numerical solutions for initial condition $c=(1,1,1)$ and $\Delta c = 10^{-n}(1,1,1)$ shows that as the difference between $c$ and $\Delta c$ approaches zero, the difference between $S(c)$ and $S(\Delta c)$ approaches the constant function $\lambda x. 0$. This is shown in the graphic below (note that these were made prior to coming up with the present definition of "system").

[image]

[Plot of the difference between solutions to the Lorenz system as $\Delta c\to0$]

[image]

[Solutions become pathological beyond $t\approx 24$, but this may be a computational artifact. I would be curious to see if anyone knows of a way to show that there is some distinct value of $t$ beyond which all solutions diverge regardless of $\Delta c$]

This would suggest that the Lorenz system is *not* chaotic. In fact it would seem that many, perhaps even most, classically "chaotic" systems are not truly chaotic by this definition.

Should we declare then that chaos theory is more-or-less bunk, then?

Well I don't think so. Instead of taking chaos to be a property which divides the universe into the orderly and disorderly, it makes intuitive sense to me that "chaos" fits into some kind of scale. It is not difficult to imagine a hierarchy of systems proceeding from least to most chaotic. As a starting point, we might take:

continuously differentiable $\subset\cdots\subset$ $n$-times differentiable $\subset\cdots\subset$ differentiable $\subset$ continuous $\subset\cdots\subset$ unrestricted

and consider the complement of the preceding classes in each succeeding class is "more" chaotic than the previous (that is, the *most* chaotic system is non-differentiable, everywhere discontinuous, etc.).

---

**Finally, the question:**

If I had the time, I would like to take a broad survey of the systems most commonly described as chaotic; then, one-by-one I could assign each system to an "order" class, adding criteria as I go until I had a definitive order-chaos scale.

Unfortunately, I am not being paid to research chaos theory, and the extent of my interaction with even well-behaved systems of differential equations can be summarised as "Oh! I've heard about those!"

So I'll settle for this:

While it is relatively easy - for a sufficiently inclusive "relative" - to show that certain chaotic systems are "continuous" (in the sense described above), it is another matter entirely to show that the same system is differentiable.

Based on the limited evidence available, I suspect that the most commonly studied chaotic systems (Lorenz system, Rossler system, n-body system, etc.) are continuous, but I do not see anything that would strongly indicate whether or not they are differentiable (the apparent smoothness of the difference in solutions may be due to limited precision).

Is it the case that the "chaotic systems" commonly considered in chaos theory are non-differentiable?

If not, then what would be a reasonable criteria for the "least" chaotic class of systems in the hierarchy?

---

**Note:**

I would guess that "if $\mathbf{f}$ is smooth and $\mathbf{g}$, then $\Vert\mathbf{f}-\mathbf{g}\Vert$ is smooth" - and this does suggest that many chaotic systems are differentiable. However, I'm not sure how well this works in the limiting case, especially considering the possibility of continuous, non-differentiable regions (the pathological portion of the Lorenz system might be one such region).

Comment: Two (important) points: there are many notions of "chaotic" and you are only mentioning the simplest of all; even your notion of "system" as a function $S\colon I\to Y^X$ is rather restrictive (have a look at any good book on differential equations: the dependence is as smooth as the vector field, but you can't in general take the same domain $X$). Of course, the case of discrete time is simpler.

Comment: @JohnB Re: "your notion of 'system' as a function $S:I\to Y^X$ is rather restrictive...you can't in general take the same domain  $X$" That's true, but it seemed like a good idea to *start* with "systems whose solutions belong to $Y^X$" rather than "systems whose solutions belong to $\bigcup_j Y^{E_j}$, where $E_j\subseteq X$ for all $j\in J$. I'm not sure of what's to be gained by beginning my first attempt at a definition with the general case. I wasn't able to find a definition of "system" that readily supports properties like continuity, but if one already exists, I'm happy to use it.

Comment: @JohnB Re: "there are many notions of 'chaotic'". While I do appreciate this, and will likely ask for an overview in another question, the present question is concerned primarily with the differentiablility of chaotic systems over the space of initial conditions (and whether or not this serves as a reasonable measure of chaos).

Comment: My point is that your attempt is at something that is well known. Since it is apparent from your comments that you insist in using yours (we need to respect this), I leave this one.

Comment: @JohnB I wasn't aware that this was well known. In looking for a way to clarify the meaning of "chaotic," every resource I found had something along the lines of "there is no agreed upon definition of chaos, but a system is generally regarded as chaotic when it is sensitive to small changes in initial conditions." Would you be able to point me to a definitive (or, at least, unambiguous) source?

Comment: There is none that everybody would agree with, mostly because we don't need a definition of chaos, instead we should study properties, either being "sensitive to small changes in initial conditions" or many other things, such as density of periodic points, positive topological entropy, ergodicity of an invariant measure equivalent to Lebesgue, exponential decay of correlations, etc.